# How to erase all data on android tablet?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, locked-out

My cousin locked my tablet trying to figure out the passcode and locked me out! Im trying to erase all data. please help.

Comment: If you want to re-gain access to your tablet, please see the [locked-out tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/locked-out/info). If you really just want to reset the device to factory settings, you might need to boot into recovery-mode and perform a factory-reset. Usually that's done by powering up the device while holding the vol+ or vol- keys; the combination often is device specific.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things you could do.

1. Boot into recovery mode, and perform a factory reset that way. Google something like "recovery mode " and the volume buttons act as the arrow keys and the power/home button as the back/select button.
2. Log into your Google account on your computer (if you aren't already logged in) ensuring that it is the same account as the one on your tablet. And go to https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager
   From there, if your device is supported, you should be able to wipe your device, or even better, change the device's password so that you can easily unlock it again.